# How to JSON.parse objects so that objects will be instances of the class?

Tags: javascript, json, prototype

I have JavaScript "Class" that makes js objects smarter. I serialize these objects to localStorage and restore them. But these restored object are not instances of a class. Restored objects are just property-sets. So, I do set __proto__ of these objects.
And I've read that using __proto__ is wrong (slow and deprecated) approach to make objects smarter.

What is smart solution for these problem? How to restore JavaScript objects so that they will be instances of the corresponding classes?

```
var showMarks = function (locals) {
    var myMarks = locals.myMarks = locals.myMarks.slice(0, 120);
    for (var i = myMarks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        myMarks[i].__proto__ = Mark.prototype;
    }
}

showMarks(JSON.parse(localStorage.myMarks));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** According to comment, I added a replacement of original literal objects foreach myMarks

You could first instanciate your class, then loop through your object's properties to set them  after instanciation

```
var mark, key;
for (var i = myMarks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    mark = new Mark();
    for (key in myMarks[i]) {
        if (myMarks[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            mark[key] = myMarks[i][key];
        }
    }
    // replace previous plain object with the new instance of Mark
    myMarks[i] = mark;
}
```

Comment: I also need Mark.init after setting properties and put newly created Mark object back to array.

Comment: @DmitryKaigorodov updated my answer, tell me if I got it wrong

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to have a method to serialize and one to unserialize your instance. JSON.stringify/parse work well for plain objects, but if you want more, you have to make your custom methods.

Example with class that has private properties:

```
function Cls(name) {
  var private_name = name; // private!
  this.getName = function() { return private_name; }
}

Cls.prototype.sayHi = function() {
  console.log(this.getName() + ' says hi!');
}

// serialization
Cls.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return JSON.stringify({ // add what you need to reconstruct the class in it's current state
    name : this.getName()
  });
}

Cls.fromJSON = function(str) {
  return new Cls(JSON.parse(str).name); // you might need to have a special case in the constructor for this
}

// usage:
var c = new Cls('me');
var serialization = c.toJSON();
var clone = Cls.fromJSON(serialization);
clone.sayHi()
```

Comment: I do not see how this solves my problem. I have single string with an array of the objects, so I could not pass JSON string to the constructor. I have JSON structure after parsing string.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand your problem. Seeing how the other answers tackle the same problem, i think the problem lies in your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can add a property indicating the class they belongs to before storing them (ie: `.__class`).
Then, you can write a function (let's say `restore(obj)`):

```
function restore(obj){
    switch(obj.__class){
        case "Class1":
            return new Class1(obj.a, obj.b);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is solution, but not of my problem. Probably, one day when my json structure will become more difficult and I will use this approach.